# How to override query parameters in actuator/prometheus to hide their values

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I don't write here often but I am facing a fun issue.
We have a spring project 2.5.x with actuator/prometheus enabled.
There are some get queries that use data we wish to hide(only a subset of the query parameters of a query, not all of them) in /actuator/prometheus as any get request is by default logged with the query parameters (which makes sense). Now I know that all that trouble could be avoided by switching to post but we cannot for the moment.

Here is what I have right now :
`http_client_requests_seconds_sum{client_name="client",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/test?query=1234&field1=value2&field2=value3",} 0.050652838`
And here is what I would like to obtain:
`http_client_requests_seconds_sum{client_name="client",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/test?query=****&field1=value2&field2=value3",} 0.050652838`

The piece I want to hide is always called query.

What I have tried so far :

- Creating a filter that should filter out the query in the logs : this works but actuator still registers the normal query

```java
@Component
@Order(1)
public class QueryParameterSanitizationFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            String requestURI = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();

            // List of URIs that require query parameter sanitization
            String[] endpointsToSanitize = {"endpoint1", "/endpoint2"};

            if (requiresSanitization(requestURI, endpointsToSanitize)) {
                SanitizedRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new SanitizedRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
                chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, response);
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    // Implement a method to check if the URI requires query parameter sanitization
    private boolean requiresSanitization(String requestURI, String[] endpointsToSanitize) {
        for (String endpoint : endpointsToSanitize) {
            if (requestURI.startsWith(endpoint)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Custom wrapper to capture the request and modify query parameters
    private static class SanitizedRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
        private String sanitizedQueryString;

        public SanitizedRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
            super(request);
            this.sanitizedQueryString = sanitizeQueryParameters(request.getQueryString());
        }

        @Override
        public String getQueryString() {
            return sanitizedQueryString;
        }

        private String sanitizeQueryParameters(String queryString) {
            if (queryString != null) {
                String[] params = queryString.split("&");
                for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    String param = params[i];
                    if (param.startsWith("param=")) {
                        // If it does, replace the value with "***"
                        params[i] = "param=***";
                    }
                }
                // Reconstruct the sanitized query string
                return String.join("&", params);
            }
            return queryString;
        }
    }
}
```

Creating a custom `HttpServletWrapper`, `HandlerInterceptor` and `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`

```java
public class QueryParameterSanitizationInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();

        String[] endpointsToSanitize = {"/endpoint1","endpoint2"};

        if (requiresSanitization(requestURI, endpointsToSanitize)) {
            SanitizedRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new SanitizedRequestWrapper(request);
            request = wrappedRequest;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private boolean requiresSanitization(String requestURI, String[] endpointsToSanitize) {
        for (String endpoint : endpointsToSanitize) {
            if (requestURI.startsWith(endpoint)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

```java
public class QueryParameterSanitizationInterceptorAdapter extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private final QueryParameterSanitizationInterceptor interceptor;

    public QueryParameterSanitizationInterceptorAdapter(QueryParameterSanitizationInterceptor interceptor) {
        this.interceptor = interceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        return interceptor.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

}
```

```java
public class SanitizedRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final String sanitizedQueryString;

    public SanitizedRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        this.sanitizedQueryString = sanitizeQueryParameters(request.getQueryString());
    }

    @Override
    public String getQueryString() {
        return sanitizedQueryString;
    }

    private String sanitizeQueryParameters(String queryString) {
        if (queryString != null) {
            // Split the query string into individual parameter-value pairs
            String[] params = queryString.split("&");
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                String param = params[i];
                // Check if the parameter starts with "query="
                if (param.startsWith("query=")) {
                    // If it does, replace the value with "***"
                    params[i] = "query=***";
                }
            }
            // Reconstruct the sanitized query string
            return String.join("&", params);
        }
        return queryString;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work so well.
Again I know that everything could be solved if we switched to post requests but for the time being it is not possible.
Anyone has any extra idea?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I fixed the issue by creating a new meterfilter that applies the desired transformation.

Comment: Switch to POST request. Kidding aside, shouldn't you just register a new tag provider for prometheus instead o trying to filter the parameters, as that will also obfuscate/hide them for controllers etc. Could you add an example of the prometheus output you want to cleanup?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add the desired output.. I edited the first post about this. I will check tag provider but we work with the default values of actuator usually!

Comment: I think you might want to have a dedicated one for the web, which only does the `uri` without the parameters **or** which obfuscates the values you want. I think the one without parameters in the `uri` is the easiest.